# Firefox video tag getVideoPlaybackQuality() is not a function

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-video, media-source

According to [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement/getVideoPlaybackQuality), `getVideoPlaybackQuality()` on `HTMLVideoElement` is available after version 25.0.

However, I tried to call it on video element in Firefox 38.1.0 and got an `getVideoPlaybackQuality is not a function` error.

Is this api actually available for Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Firefox MSE bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778617),

> Firefox has a whitelist limiting MSE (to YouTube, Netflix, and Dailymotion) while we fix some compatibility bugs. The whitelist will likely be removed in Firefox 42, making MSE available to all websites.

Answer (score 1):

Did you catch the footnote in Mozilla's documentation ... that the function is only available if you switch on a config flag?

Load `about:config` in Firefox and search for the `media.mediasource.enabled` flag, then set it to true and try your function call again.

**EDIT**: If I'm reading correctly, the release notes for [Firefox 37](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/37.0/releasenotes/) and [Firefox 38](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/38.0/releasenotes/) seem to indicate that the MediaSource API is currently implemented for YouTube only. However, it's enabled for [Firefox Nightlies](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) right now.

Comment: `media.mediasource.enabled` is enabled. Also `MediaSource` is not available.